# How to repair / reinstall magento system files without loosing anything (theme,database etc)?

Tags: php, magento

http://www.toy-kraft.com/index.php/admin

Hi there,

When you click on the link above you'd see only blank page.
Can somebody help me to resolve this?

**Error log**

```
[Mon Jul 06 03:15:51.777914 2015] [access_compat:error] [pid 17856] [client 89.248.160.217:63348] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home/toykraft/public_html/includes/js  
[Mon Jul 06 03:15:51.034340 2015] [access_compat:error] [pid 17860] [client 89.248.160.217:63323] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home/toykraft/public_html/includes/FCKeditor  
[Mon Jul 06 03:15:50.279573 2015] [access_compat:error] [pid 17858] [client 89.248.160.217:63298] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home/toykraft/public_html/includes/fckeditor
```

Comment: Did you tried disabling compiler and increasing your PHP memory limit ?

Comment: yup, bro. disabled compiler and it worked. thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your Error Log it shows that you have enabled Compilation. you can disable the compilation by edit the `includes/config.php` in includes folder by comment both lines:

```
#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
#define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
```

and clear cache.